# Sync different local and remote SQL databases

Tags: sql, database, synchronization, remote-server, bidirectional

This is the scenario:

One local **program A** stores data in a local MySQL 5.x **database Db_A**.
Other remote **program B** stores data in a remote MySQL 5.x **database Db_B**.

The **programs and databases are different** but they are sharing the same stock of products, categories, etc. That's why I need to keep both of them updated if the other one changes. There is no date column in the products/categories tables (no column to register the insert/update/delete).

If the program A adds/modifies/deletes a product in database Db_A, I need to update the equivalent tables in the remote database Db_B. Same as reverse (Remote->Local). But **It's not necessary to do it in real-time. I need a sync script that could check for differencies, and could update both databases, I don't want to modify the programs.** Just a script that could be called to execute the sync between the tables.

How should I do it?
I'm running Windows on local server and the program A is running here. I can access the remote database (of Product B) from local server. I prefer to code in PHP, Python.

Thanks very much.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Comment: Actually, I think the database engine is irrelevant in this case.  For @amparo, the best answer is to get local program A to talk directly to database B.

Comment: They are MySQL, 5.x.


A php local script, that when called localy, could check if there has been modifications in any side, and that could insert/update/delete in the local database and in the remote database, to keep both stocks updated, will be ok?
 
But how to to determine which database has the last updated state, if there are no date columns?